# How do I determine if an iOS app is built with Flash?

Tags: flash, ios

Is FarmVille on the iOS built with Flash?  And if so, how can you tell?  Are there certain flags that exist in the form of certain files or magic numbers within the .app folder hierarchy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell if a iOS app is built with Adobe's "Packager for iPhone", for Flash/AIR based applications, by opening up the .ipa file for the app on a Mac.

There is probably some step by step guide out there somewhere, but basically, you locate the .ipa file (that has been transferred to the Mac, by synching apps from a iOS device via iTunes or by other means) for the app, change the file extension to zip, unzip it, go to the Payload folder and select "Show Package Contents" on the application file.

Apps built with "Packager for iPhone" will have a META-INF/AIR folder with a application.xml file in it, other apps won't. The application.xml uses the http://ns.adobe.com/air/application namespace, so it is no secret.

Comment: Perfect, figured it was something that simple, but I wasn't sure of the specifics.  Appreciate it.

Comment: It appears that it is NOT a Flash app.  I have been curious in particular due to trying to figure out if anyone has been able to get Store Kit to work yet with a Flash app.

Answer (score 0):

No easy way to tell unless the Flash to iOS compiler flags it as such and you can manage to decompile it to see. And I doubt it does flag it given Apple's allergic reaction to the stuff.

Comment: Hmm.  Are you speaking from experience here?  From being in the Air and Adobe betas previously, I have seen quite a bit in the way of the initial war that erupted behind the scenes.  There was a way for Apple to indeed isolate the difference, however I've not poked around to actually see if I could detect the difference.  I am wondering if the Air bin is compiled right into the mach-o bin or if there is a linked support package with iOS Air apps.

Comment: I don't know. No one really knows what Apple is checking for. All I know is that the final app has to be HTML, CSS, JS and/or Objective-C

Comment: Apple has changed that back, it is now permitted to use third party tools. They removed the part of the developer license agreement that previously said that "Applications must be originally written in Objective-C, C, C++, or JavaScript as executed by the iPhone OS WebKit engine". http://daringfireball.net/2010/09/app_store_guidelines

Comment: @Lars: I was referring to the outputted code. That's the key now.

Answer (score -1):

iOS cannot run flash applications, and I would imagine that the adobe flash->iOS app tools are not capable of translating such a complicated app well.

Comment: Flash Package for iOS works great and is capable of very complex apps as though they were iOS apps from everything I've seen. There are just a few questions that it begs and if FarmVille was developed with this then it would help shed some light on a few things.